# Json.NET compatibility with .NET 4.6

Tags: .net, json, json.net

When attempting to contact someone from http://www.newtonsoft.com/json, it was mentioned to post here first. I searched around a bit and cannot seem to find an exact answer. I am attempting to find out if the latest version of Json.NET is compatible with .NET 4.6. Our development team will be using Visual Studio 2015. Any information that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Jerry

Comment: Have you tried adding the reference in a throw-away project?

Comment: .NET is generally backward-compatible. Try it and see, don't be lazy.

Comment: Yes it is compatible

Comment: First of all I will apologize for any inconvenience I may have caused. Honestly, I am just an intern that was thrown onto this project with little to no knowledge. I am not a coder or a programmer, I was just trying to do my best and get the information they asked me to find. If I could test it myself, then I would have without question. Sorry again and thanks for the replies.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not support for Newtonsoft.

Comment: @WaiHaLee Newtonsoft suggests to ask here if answers cannot be found in the documentation. That's the only reason I posted here.
https://gyazo.com/f5be387275e7d30368931e6f23b575a7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Json.Net absolutely is compatible with .NET 4.6 and Visual Studio 2015.

It appears the [main documentation page](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) may be a little out of date on this point as it does not list .NET 4.6 specifically, but does list all previous versions 2.0 through 4.5.  The project is actively maintained and the [most recent release](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases) was just 11 days ago as of this writing.

Anecdotally, my team has been using Json.Net successfully with 4.6 and VS 2015 for some time now with no issues.

Comment: Thank you very much for being understanding and taking the time to post an answer! Greatly Appreciated!